# Wakanda Studio crashes upon opening a solution, project

Tags: crash, project, wakanda

Wakanda Studio (Ent. recent release), is crashing upon opening a project.

The answer to this problem has been posted on the Wakanda Forum, which I cannot access.

Comment: Does it crash when opening every solution or only one solution? Does it crash when creating a new solution?

Comment: You should declare a bug on [Wakanda Issues](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues) or open a ticket on the [support website](https://support.wakanda.io)

Comment: It began crashing when editing a project script. It crashed only opening that project. I created a new project and copied the contents of the crashing project into the new project, and it did not crash.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have full (read/write) access to the solution (<kbd>.waSolution</kbd> file, project folders, etc.).

Also make sure that the <kbd>.waSolution</kbd> file refers to existing <kbd>.waProject</kbd> and <kbd>.waSettings</kbd> files.

You can also clear the preference folders located at the following locations:

> C:\Users{Name}\AppData\Roaming\Wakanda Studio
>   C:\Users{Name}\AppData\Roaming\Wakanda Server
>   C:\Users{Name}\AppData\Roaming\Wakanda Enterprise Studio
>   C:\Users{Name}\AppData\Roaming\Wakanda Enterprise Server
>   C:\Users{Name}\AppData\Local\Wakanda Studio

Rename the folders above when Wakanda is not running and then launch Wakanda to let the application recreate the default preference files.

Answer (score 1):

The studio crashing bug was solved by creating a new project, and copying into it from the crashing project all the .js files, etc.